# ¿Ayuda para buscar en un arreglo un nombre ingresado por teclado y desplegar el indice en el que se encuentra dentro del arreglo?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

```
  ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<>();
  nombres.add("Pepe");
  nombres.add("Juan");
  nombres.add("Oscar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion `indexOf` que devuelve el indice del elemento si es encontrado, en caso contrario devuelve `-1`

```
ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<>();
  nombres.add("Pepe");
  nombres.add("Juan");
  nombres.add("Oscar");
nombres.indexOf("Juan"); // devuelve 1
nombres.indexOf("Pedro"); // devuelve -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pedir algo por teclado puedes usar `Scanner` e `indexOf` para saber la posición del nombre en el arreglo. He hecho el código y lo he comentado paso por paso.

**Código:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        // ArrayList de tipo String
        ArrayList<String> arreglo = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // Arregar nombres al ArrayList
        arreglo.add("Pepe");
        arreglo.add("Juan");
        arreglo.add("Oscar");
        
        // Pedir un nombre por teclado
        String nuevoNombre;
        System.out.print("Ingrese un nombre: ");
        nuevoNombre = scanner.nextLine();
        
        // Agregar el nuevo nombre en el ArrayList
        arreglo.add(nuevoNombre);
        
        // Cerrar Scanner
        scanner.close();
        
        // Imprimir arreglo
        for (String nombre : arreglo) {
            System.out.println(nombre);
            
            // Posición del nombre ingresado por teclado
            if (nombre.equals(nuevoNombre))
                System.out.println("Nombre encontrado en la posición " + arreglo.indexOf(nuevoNombre));
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Ingrese un nombre: Maria
>
> Pepe
>
> Juan
>
> Oscar
>
> Maria
>
> Nombre encontrado en la posición 3

Espero haberte ayudado.